# WordPress GUID PermaLinks - should I change them?

Tags: wordpress

I'm moving a WordPress blog from:

www.oldsite.com/blog/

www.newsite.com

When I export the XML Blog Post file it contains URL reference to the old domain for each blog post, for example:

```
<guid isPermaLink="false">http://www.oldiste.com/bog/?p=1275</guid>
*** This will be wrong when imported to new site ***
```

Before I import the file into the new WordPress site should I change each instance of the incorrect GUID file?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't do it when moving database from one production site to another new production site. [This article](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Important_GUID_Note) explained the reasons very well.

From a local dev site to a production site, you should. But make sure the `guid` and the real permalink point to the same content. You should follow [this guidelines](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#Changing_Your_Domain_Name_and_URLs).